# How do I open a jQuery dialog and auto-set its title to the attribute in the HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div that I'm setting a `title` attribute on:

```
<div id="test" title="Test Dialog">Some test</div>
```

Then I open a dialog with it:

```
$('#test').dialog({
    title: $(this).attr('title')
});
```

The first time this dialog opens, the title is set successfully. However, if I close the dialog and re-open it, the title will be blank. This is because, the first time jQuery opens the dialog, it copies the element and removes the `title` tag. Is there a way to get the behavior I want, where it reads the title from the `title` attribute every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in the `open` event, like so:

```
$("#test").dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { 
      $(this).dialog( "option", "title", $(this).attr('title') );
   }
});
```